# How to expose a headless service for a Elasticsearch StatefulSet externally in Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, kubernetes

**Problem Summary**

The goal is to expose the Elasticsearch Nodes endpoints externally which are internally addressed as:

```
elasticsearch-master-0.elastic.svc.cluster.local:9200
elasticsearch-master-1.elastic.svc.cluster.local:9200 
elasticsearch-master-2.elastic.svc.cluster.local:9200
```

This uses a StatefulSet and a headless service for service discovery within the cluster.

The constraint is that this external service be able to address the brokers specifically.

Whats the right (or one possible) way of going about this? Is it possible to expose a external service per elasticsearch-x.elastic.svc.cluster.local:9200?

Comment: If your  issue is solved, can you please provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: Salik47, thanks for making an answer. I have however the impression that you have removed much of the information which was initially contained in the question. Please review and make sure that the info needed for answering the question is still in there, so that somebody else could theoretically also/still answer it. (To be clear, I do not understand enough detail technically to judge myself, I really ask you to just review and confirm). If you identifed that information which was unneeded and only distracting and then removed it for making a focused question, then you did great of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem is this way:

In official [ElasticSearch helm chart](https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts/tree/v7.17.3) there are 2 services created:

1. elasticsearch-master - 9200/TCP, 9300/TCP
2. elasticsearch-master-headless

I created the first service of `type: LoadBalancer` with of class `nlb` with following annotations

```
annotations: {
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-name: "es-nlb",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: "external",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-nlb-target-type: "instance",
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: "internet-facing"
}
```

Which creates 2 listener ports i.e. `9200` & `9300` at ELB end and linked with target group pointing to the application

`<es-nlb-dns>:9200`

`<es-nlb-dns>:9300`

Now i used these endpoints to connect with the springboot data elasticsearch client.